# Not displaying millions of point in Qt/Opengl ( MAC OS X )

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, cpu, nvidia

I'm doing an Qt/Opengl application and I'm drawing like 8 millions of points ( 3 = triangle )

So in some computer ( windows ), its drawing all the points without problems, but in my retina 15" ( i7, nvdia ..), sometimes its not displaying all the points and it's necessary to move over there for displaying it.

So, is there a solution about this ?

I'm drawing them like this :

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, test[0].send_coordText());
glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[0].send_terrain());
glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, indice_degra_de.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,indice_degra_de.constData());
```

Comment: How do you draw the points? What do you do? Code?

Comment: I edited my post. Im drawing a terrain using points from .xyz file ( ortho )